# My GPU doesn't support any of the 4 options in GPU settings

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu, performance, windows

I am so tired of only using the CPU for my renders because It's a bit slow and also makes me worry pretty much in the process about my CPU surviving it. I checked how I can force Blender to use my GPU.
But all 4 options just...
My GPU doesn't support them.

My GPU:  Radeon RX 560 Series

and my CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-4160 CPU @ 3.60GHz

I use the newest Steam version

(I think it has to do anything with my Windows because it got badly damaged when I got my PC. (There was no shutdown button and no restart button, and Windows acted weirdly sometimes, and some games ran badly))